# C# Initialising an array of labels "Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, label

I have a member variable declared as follows:

```
private Label[] dice = new Label[numberOfDice];
```

and when I try to initialize the values within `dice` with labels on my form I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'" in this line:

```
dice[i] = dieName;
```

I understand that `dieName` is a string but the `dice` array wants me to provide it with the name of an actual label in my form. In my form, I have five labels named die1, die2, ..., die5.

Here is the function where I am initializing the `dice` array:

```
private void InitializeLabels()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
   {
       string dieName = String.Format("die{0}", i + 1);
       dice[i] = dieName;
   }
}
```

I know I could just do this:

```
dice[0] = die1;
dice[1] = die2;
...
dice[4] = die5;
```

but I would like to use a cleaner method like the for-loop above.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Well that's not very helpful. You can't do that exactly. You may have some luck if you look into using a DataRepeater control.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it is clear that you are assigning a string type value(`dieName`) to a variable of type `Label` so you met with such error. I think you are trying to set the value of the Label Text, if so you should use the `.Text` property of the Label Control. If you want to give a name for the Label means you should use the `.Name` property, Now you can take a look into the snippet to achieve the target.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
{
    string dieName = String.Format("die{0}", i + 1);
    dice[i].Text = dieName;
    dice[i].Name = dieName;
}
```

Comment: warm welcome; appreciate the downvote, and let me know the reason please

Comment: In my form I have already created and named the die1, die2, etc. labels. So would doing dice[i].Name make dice[i] refer to that label specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void InitializeLabels()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
   {
       string dieName = String.Format("die{0}", i + 1);
       dice[i].Text = dieName;
   }
}
```

or if they aren't initialised

```
private void InitializeLabels()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
   {
       string dieName = String.Format("die{0}", i + 1);
       dice[i].Text = new Label{Parent = this, 
                                Text = dieName, 
                                Size = new Size(50,20), 
                                Location = new Point(i * 50, 0)};
   }
}
```